# No handleMessage method, in new sforce-partner-api versions' PartnerConnection class( For Email2Case Agent)

Tags: email2case

I was using PartnerConnection class' handleEmailMessage method(old sforce-partner-api version) for EmailToCase Agent. Now I am using sforce-partner-api-29.0.0 jar but there is no PartnerConnection' handleEmailMessage method.

Why this method is not supported to use?
   and
   Is there any method equivalent to handleEmailMessage  in sforce-partner-api-29.0.0 jar?